# TFS SDK - How can I tell what fields were changed in a revision?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I need to tell which fields were changed as part of a revision. At the moment I'm checking using

```
foreach (Field f in revision.Fields) {
    if (Equals(f.OriginalValue, f.Value)) { continue; }
    // do something with changed field
}
```

however, this code has an issue and that is that it doesn't list fields, which were changed but to the same value. Looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.revision(v=vs.120).aspx I don't see a way to do so, but since TFS does track this kind of thing (== visual studio & web interface both shows changed fields even to the same value), it should be possible. But I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: What do you mean "Visual studio & web interface both shows changed fields even to the same value", according to my test, if a field value doesn't changed, it won't show in the History tab. It only lists those changed fields. Here is a sceenshot(https://1drv.ms/i/s!AopgZUVNxLwJgUBTOBuV7MILi4FS)? If I misunderstand your issue, please explain it to me.

Comment: And I have tested the code you posted above, the result it the same with which you see from the web page, it only shows those changed fields' value. I just confused abou "fields which were changed but to the same value", could you please tell me what does change to the same value mean?

Comment: when I do `work_item.fields["Field"] = "value"; work_item.Save(); work_item.fields["Field"] = "value"; work_item.Save();` it creates two new revisions, but the `Field` field has some value in both. So my code shows them as not changed. But visual studio correctly list it in the changed fields..

Comment: I tested the code you posted all above and here(https://1drv.ms/t/s!AopgZUVNxLwJgUFzjpAa1A-kSzGB) is my sample. The result is if I save the workitem field with the same value twice, it doesn't generate a new revision. The wi.Revisions.Count doesn't increase, it still the same. If possible, could you please share your code completely.

Comment: sure, my code is here http://pastebin.com/033RZvFm , I see only two significant differences. 1) I used `History` field instead of `Priority`, could or could not be the difference 2) the change was done across separate runs on the program, not like in you case in one function.

Comment: It's the first reason. The history field is not like the Priority.

Answer (score 0):

The history value couldn't be changed by this way: `work_item.fields["History"] = "value"`. Workitem History are not support to changed and modified. It generates according to what you have edit on this workitem.

And this `if (Equals(f.OriginalValue, f.Value)) { continue; }` won't list the history field. The history field is not simple like other fields(Priority, title,etc). The Revisions represent History of workitems.

Update:

To get which fields changed in each revisions, you could try to list all info in the revisions and write method to compare them. This is an example:
http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx

Comment: How I'm supposed to add new comment to work item then? In `Revisions` collection it's represented by `History` field of each `Revision`. How can I add new revision then with some `History` field? My approach does work, new revision with comment is correctly created. Only issue is with my original question. If what I'm doing is incorrect, what is proper way to add new revision with comment?

Comment: @Paladin What I want to said is that the revision couldn't be created or edited by yourself. When other field's value changed and you save workitem, a new revision is created automatically.

Comment: I agree. I changed the `History` field, saved the workitem and new revision was created. But my original question was how can I tell what fields where changed in each revision.